# boost::intrusive_ptr constructor ambiguity using a class' 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, templates, boost, ambiguity

The offending code:

```
template<typename T>
class SharedObject {
 public:
  typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<T> Pointer;
  typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<T const> ConstPointer;
  inline Pointer GetPointer() {
    return Pointer(this); //Ambiguous call here
  }
  inline ConstPointer GetPointer() const {
    return ConstPointer(this);
  }
  ...
```

and used like this:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass: public SharedObject<SomeClass<T> > {
 public:
  static inline boost::intrusive_ptr<SomeClass<T> > Create() {
    return (new SomeClass)->GetPointer();
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto v = SomeClass<int>::Create();
}
```

GCC (4.4.1) with boost 1.41 gives this error upon instatiating the first (non-const) version of GetPointer():

```
error: call of overloaded ‘intrusive_ptr SharedObject<SomeClass<int> >* const)’ is ambiguous
boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:118: note: candidates are: boost::intrusive_ptr<T>::intrusive_ptr(boost::intrusive_ptr<T>&&) [with T = SomeClass<int>] <near match>
boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:94:  note:                 boost::intrusive_ptr<T>::intrusive_ptr(const boost::intrusive_ptr<T>&) [with T = SomeClass<int>] <near match>
boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:70:  note:                 boost::intrusive_ptr<T>::intrusive_ptr(T*, bool) [with T = SomeClass<int>] <near match>
```

To my less than arcane skills in C++, I can't see why there is any ambiguity at all. The two canditates at lines 188 and 94 takes an existing intrusive_ptr rvalue reference, which `SharedObject::this` certainly is not. The final candidate however is a perfect match (the bool argument is optional).

Anyone care to enlighten me as to what the problem is?

**EDIT+answer**: I finally realized that in

```
  inline Pointer GetPointer() {
    return Pointer(this); //Ambiguous call here
  }
```

`this` refers to SharedObject while the Pointer typedef is SomeClass. (Which is pretty much what Butterworth pointed out right away).

```
  inline Pointer GetPointer() {
    return Pointer(static_cast<C*>(this));
  }
```

Since I know `this` to really be SomeClass, inheriting from SharedObject, a static_cast makes the template class go 'round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say:

```
typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<T> Pointer;
```

you are declaring a type which is an intrusive pointer to an `int` (because `T` is an `int` at that point), when the template is instantiated in your code. Your SharedObject class is not an `int`, so you can't instantiate such an intrusive pointer using `this`.

**Edit:** OK, I misunderstood your code,  I'll try again. At:

```
return Pointer(this); //Ambiguous call here
```

this is a SharedObject , as per the error messages, however the pointer is typedefed to a SomeClass I think.

Your code is incredibly hard to understand  - whatever it is you are trying to do, there must be a simpler way. And you seem to be missing a virtual destructor (and maybe a virtual function) in the base class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. I added a more specific example in the original question. As far as I can see, ShareObject is instantiated with `SomeClass<T>` passed as T, which as far as I understand makes `typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<T> Pointer;` work as intended? Do I fail to understand your answer, or was my initial example too vague?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped me figure things out.<br><br>And as for my goal, it's actually not as complicated as it looks. I put the full class at http://paste.ubuntu.com/360614/ for reference. (I'm not missing a virtual destructor afaik).